# c++11 random: why different range of int and real?

Tags: algorithms, c++11, random

In the c++11, we now have <[random](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random)> to produce random number.
About uniform distributions, we have following `int_distribution` and `double_distribution`:

```
uniform_int_distribution-produces integer values evenly distributed across a range

uniform_real_distribution-produces real values evenly distributed across a range
```

The first produces random integer values i, uniformly distributed on the closed interval **[a, b]**, but the second, ie real one, produces random floating-point values i, uniformly distributed on the interval **[a, b)**

**Question: why int and real distribution have different range, ie for one `b]` is inclusive but for another `b)` is exclusive?**

**If it is related with the algorithms behind, I would like to know what are they and where are the differences.** Or preferences about it.

Comment: Related reading: [Random in C++11 with closed interval](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22581737/439793).

Comment: I cannot answer definitely, but consider the range `0..1`. With integers, an open range would always return 0. With floating point, it cannot return 1, but there are a very large number of values it can return. If you need different behavior, you are free to define your own distribution object.

Comment: For int distributions there's two use cases: either you care about the number of values but not the range (e.g. for simulating probabilistic events) or you do care about the range. For the former an open interval is more useful because it's easier to calculate the number of values (`max - min`). For the latter case you already know the `min` and `max` you want to get so the inclusive format is easier. It seems they're catering to the latter use case. I'm not sure what's the rationale behind excluding the maximum in the real distribution though.

Answer (score 2):

`Uniform_real_distribution` had a closed range until 2006, after which it was changed to a half-open range [because developers are said to be more comfortable with it](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3926.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Closed intervals "feel" more natural in a discrete setting.
Half-open intervals "feel" more natural in a continuous setting (well, they feel more natural even for rationals, but...).

I would be surprised by a "generates integer numbers" function that didn't use intervals if I gave it an explicit minimum and maximum, but I'm essentially OK with a single-argument one that takes rand(N) and gives me a result in [0, N-1], but if I give it rand(a, b) I actually want [a, b].

Comment: Question asks for a reason, a "feeling" is not a reason, at least not when defining a standard for a programming library.

Comment: Half-open intervals are very natural in discrete settings. For example, array indexing and slicing, or `range` in Python, or any other interval of the form `start <= x < end`. See also: [Dijkstra's take on it](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html).

Comment: I think open intervals make more sense in the continuous setting in statistics since the probability of any one point is zero the difference melts away. However, since we are programmers and actually mean a fine grained discrete settings, yeah maybe half open is more natural, don't really know. Just my tuppence worth.

Comment: @delnan Fun fact: closed intervals are more natural with 1-based arrays.